# Javascript Canvas 2d collision detection

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, collision, detection

Trying to detect collision between two squares while going through an array. On detecting collision in the left side, I can't seem to get the square to stop clipping one pixel into the other one.

When moving left, on the black square I am checking the top left X coordinate, top left Y coordinate, bottom left X coordinate and bottom Y coordinate to see if it detects collision.

```
<pre>function collision(map,x,y,e) {


  if (map[Math.floor((y-1)/25)][(Math.floor((x)/25))] == 1 || map[Math.floor((y+26)/25)][(Math.floor(x/25))] == 1 && e==37) {
    return true;
}



   if (map[Math.floor((y)/25)][(Math.floor((x)/25))] == 1 || map[Math.floor((y+25)/25)][(Math.floor((x)/25))] == 1 && e==38) {
    return true;
    }

}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

    ctx.clearRect(x,y,25,25);

    switch(e.keyCode) {

  case 37:

  if (!collision(map,x,y,e.keyCode)) {
  x--;
  }
break;
<code>
```

Any tips on another way to go about this is greatly appreciated. I've tried looking at the examples on Mozilla's github (https://github.com/mozdevs/gamedev-js-tiles/blob/gh-pages/square/logic-grid.js) but I can't wrap my mind around the way they check tile collision using the reduce function.

JS Fiddle below

https://jsfiddle.net/bcvwubw0/36/